# Clear() method not working in appium for password field

Tags: selenium, appium

I am working on appium and facing a problem while clearing password field. Using clear() method to achieve the same in fact using same method to clear username and its working fine.

```
@Test
public void testCal() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    Pojoclass.username(driver).clear();
    Pojoclass.password(driver).clear();
    String FilePath = "C:/Users/jayant.gupta/Desktop/JCB project/JCB_mobile_automation/login_testdata.xls";
    Excelconfig r = new Excelconfig();
    r.readlogin(FilePath, 1, driver);

    driver.navigate().back();
    WebElement login_button = driver.findElement(By.id("buttonLogin"));
    login_button.click();
    driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.jiteshmohite.ycce:id/password")).clear();
```

**Replace**

com.example.jiteshmohite.ycce

**With**

Your package name.

Hope these help you.